# How to make a max auto-fill track size for my CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with the following styles.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
```

It works perfectly when the screen gets too small, but when the screen is too big it looks funky because `auto-fill` just fills the track. Is there a way to set a max auto-fill so that only a certain amount of cells show up in a single track?

Comment: have a look at `@media screen and (max-width`

Comment: I can't use media queries because I'm using css in js

Comment: then use `window.matchMedia("(max-width:`

Comment: Not clear what you want. Have you tried `auto-fit` instead?

Comment: It's cool I just set a max width of 1000px but I'm going to leave this open just incase someone finds a way to define the max track size.

Comment: Consider posting a working example, so we can reproduce the problem and provide better feedback.